# firebase to create buttons android studio

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-studio

I'm using Realtime Database (Firebase) in my android application with Java and I wanted to store data to create custom buttons every time a user opens my app. I dont want a user's custom buttons to disappear when the app is closed, but I cant seem to get this right.

I tried saving a list in my databse as so:
`mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("list").setValue(list);`
and retrieving like so:
`schede=(List)mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("list");`
But I get this error on the latter piece of code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

I'm also open to alternative solutions, firebase seems the best to me.

Comment: You're trying to get "schede" instead of "list". Get the list and then take the button the user needs from the list.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sorry, I've adjusted the question properly

Comment: You didn't retrieve the data you just have a reference. You need to add an eventlistener to get the values.

Comment: I tried adding an eventlistener "OnDataChange" but then how I retrieve when I want to (at the start of the activity to create the buttons), and not only when data is changed?

Comment: You need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

Comment: Ho do I retrieve it then?

Comment: `onDataChange` executes immediately so you just need to take the value from the snapshot.

Comment: But what if I want to retrieve at the start of the application, and not when I assign the listener?

Comment: You may have to use `SharedPreferences`.